# For these gauge transformations in electromagnetism, $\phi\to \phi-\partial_t \lambda$ and $\vec A\to \vec A+\nabla\lambda$, why do the signs differ?

Tags: electromagnetism, metric-tensor, potential, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance

I was looking at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4860279/) on Mathematics S.E, as I would like to know the origin of the signs in the gauge transformations of the scalar and vector potentials components, $\phi$ and $\vec A$, of the four-vector potential $A^\mu=\left(\phi, \vec A\right)$:
$$\phi\to \phi-\frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial t},\quad \vec A\to \vec A+\nabla\lambda\tag{A}$$ where $\lambda$ is a gauge parameter; an arbitrary function of spacetime.

---

For the purposes of this question I will follow all the same notation and conventions as the linked question, including the Minkowski sign convention, $\eta= \mathrm{diag}(1,-1,-1,-1)$. I know that this question may seem better placed on Mathematics S.E, but I would like to see a physicists take on this. Moreover, I'm not equipped to understand the answers given by the mathematicians.

---

The OP in the linked question wanted to know why the transformations in $(\mathrm{A})$ can be written as one compact equation,
$$A_\mu\to A_\mu+\partial_\mu\lambda\tag{B}$$

The answer given is way beyond my comprehension, the user that gave the answer was talking about "musical isomorphisms", not something I can relate to.

---

So instead of starting with the transformations in $(\mathrm{A})$ and trying to understand how they combine compactly into $(\mathrm{B})$, I will try the reverse approach.

Given $A^\mu=\left(\phi, \vec A\right)$ then the covariant version is $A_\mu=\left(\phi, -\vec A\right)$, (this was pointed out in an answer to another question asked by the same OP [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4861221/show-that-partial-mu-phi-ast-a-mu-phi-a-mu-phi-ast-partial-mu-phi-a-mu?noredirect=1&lq=1)).

Now, writing out the components
$$A_\mu\to\left(A_0+\partial_0 \lambda, -A_1-\partial_1 \lambda, -A_2-\partial_2 \lambda, -A_3-\partial_3 \lambda\right)$$
$$=\left(\phi+\frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial t}, -\vec A - \nabla \lambda\right)\tag{C}$$
So according to $(\mathrm{C})$ the gauge transformation components of $A_\mu$ are
$$\phi\to \phi+\frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial t},\quad \vec A\to -\vec A-\nabla\lambda\tag{D}$$

But these signs in $(\mathrm{D})$ are totally different to that of $(\mathrm{A})$.

Does anyone know how the scalar and vector gauge transformations in $(\mathrm{A})$ can be deduced from $(\mathrm{B})$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We already know the [4-position](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-vector#Four-position) is $x^\mu = (t, \vec{x})$
and the [4-gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-vector#Four-gradient) is
$$\partial_\mu = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}
 = \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t},\vec{\nabla} \right) \tag{1a}$$
or equivalently $$\partial^\mu
 = \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t},-\vec{\nabla} \right) \tag{1b}$$

Starting with the relativistic gauge transformation
$$A_\mu \to A_\mu + \partial_\mu \lambda \tag{B}$$
is conceptually problematic, because we do not know yet
what is the correct 4-potential $A_\mu$.
It is not obvious if the correct choice must be
$A_\mu=(\phi,\vec{A})$ or $A_\mu=(\phi,-\vec{A})$.
So we need to do it the other way round and start with
the classical gauge transformation
$$\phi\to \phi-\frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial t},
\quad \vec A\to \vec A+\vec{\nabla}\lambda\tag{A}$$

We can write (A) as
$$(\phi,\vec{A}) \to (\phi,\vec{A})-
\left(\frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial t},-\vec{\nabla}\lambda \right)$$

Here we see, that because of
the $-\vec{\nabla}$ we can use $\partial^\mu$ from (1b),
but not $\partial_\mu$ from (1a). We get
$$(\phi,\vec{A}) \to (\phi,\vec{A})-\partial^\mu\lambda$$
To make this a valid 4-vector equation (with all upper $\mu$),
we need to define $A^\mu=(\phi,\vec{A})$ and get
$$A^\mu \to A^\mu-\partial^\mu\lambda$$
or equivalently with $A_\mu=(\phi,-\vec{A})$
$$A_\mu \to A_\mu-\partial_\mu\lambda$$

Answer (score 2):

Your result is almost correct, you just have two sign errors.
Lets start with your transformation (B) and be careful with the signs.
The four derivative is defined in such a way, that they have a positive sign if they have a lower index:
\begin{equation*}
\partial_\mu = \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}, \frac{\partial}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial}{\partial z}  \right)
\end{equation*}
Therefore the right hand side of your equation (C) should be
\begin{equation*}
\left(\phi + \frac{\partial\lambda}{\partial t}, -\vec A + \nabla\lambda\right) 
\end{equation*}
Your second mistake is that the left hand side of the same equation also has a lowered index, and therefore is
\begin{equation*}
\left(\phi, -\vec A \right)
\end{equation*}
The four-potential therefore should transform as
\begin{equation*}
\phi \rightarrow \phi + \frac{\partial\lambda}{\partial t},\quad \vec A \rightarrow \vec A - \nabla\lambda
\end{equation*}
This is exactly the opposite of your equation (A). To recover it you either have to apply the transformation with $-\lambda$ instead of $\lambda$ or use
\begin{equation*}
A_\mu \rightarrow A_\mu - \partial_\mu \lambda
\end{equation*}
as transformation law.

Answer (score 2):

This sign comes from the fact that ($g^{00}=+1$ assumed) $$\partial^\mu = \left ( \frac{d~}{dt},  -{\vec \nabla} \right ) \,.$$

You can avoid such issues by using covariant notation throughout.

Answer (score 1):

The perhaps underwhelming answer is, *it doesn't matter, but you need to stick with the convention that you choose* (when raising and lowering indices.) To see why, consider the following thought experiment: let $\eta = \lambda(-t, x)$. Then $A^\mu \mapsto A'^\mu := (\phi + \partial_t\eta, \vec A + \vec \nabla \eta )$.

Comment: That sure is underwhelming, if it really doesn't matter then why is it that every single source I've seen quotes these gauge transformations as $\phi\to \phi-\partial_t \lambda$ and $\vec A\to \vec A+\nabla\lambda$? I'm yet to find even *one* book/webpage that writes the scalar gauge transformation as $\phi\to \phi+\partial_t \lambda$ (and still with $\vec A\to \vec A+\nabla\lambda$, so that both gauge transformations have a positive sign). It's almost like there is some hidden meaning/reasoning in the minus sign for the scalar gauge transformation.

Comment: So, it's slightly more transparent to observe the gauge symmetry $A_\mu\rightarrow A_\mu' = A_\mu + \partial_\mu \lambda$ from the definition of $F_{\mu\nu} \propto \partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu$, and this would require working with $\partial^\mu\lambda$ (rather than the more 'natural' $\partial_\mu\lambda$) when evaluating $A^\mu$ from a vector source $j^\mu$. I would guess that this explains the minus sign (although it's worth mentioning that the + - - - convention is used in Landau vol.. 2, and probably other references that emphasize the role of proper time.)